# PayPal Form Donate Button Show Billing Info

Tags: html, forms, paypal

I have a paypal form that I want users to enter their billing information into then push that information into paypal automatically. I can get the information to prepopulate using the HTML form fields, but when the paypal page loads, the users must click a very small "Continue" under "Don't have a paypal account?". Is there a way to avoid them needing to click continue and have the billing information form automatically show? code below

```
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="fakemail@fakey.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
Amount: <input type="text" name="amount" /><br/>
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name" /><br/>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" /><br/>
Email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br/>
<input type="radio" name="item_name" value="Purple" />Purple
<input type="radio" name="item_name" value="Gold" />Gold
<input type="radio" name="item_name" value="Other" />Other
<input type="radio" name="item_name" value="College" />College<br/>
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-DonationsBF:btn_donate_SM.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you switch to the [Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/) instead of using Payments Standard (buttons) you'll have more freedom over this.  That's going to require more programming knowledge, though.

If you're familiar with PHP my [PayPal library](http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/) will make this very simple for you.

Comment: I am familiar with PHP and have the programming knowledge needed. The only catch is, I'm passing this information to a friend who may not. They also need a quick fix for something, so I was hoping there was a way to do this with the button. I did send them the API link though. Is there no way to do this with a donate button?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  The standard buttons are based on cookies.  If anybody has ever signed in to a PayPal account on the computer that is being used for payment it will default to the PayPal login.  If the cookies are completely clear it will make the guest checkout option more noticeable.  You can confirm this by clearing your browser cache/cookies and you'll see the checkout page changes.